# Rails CMS for inserting multi-language text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I'm looking for a Ruby on Rails CMS and I want it to support multi-language text input.

I mean, for example, I would like to insert a text into a section, in three different languages. But, I don't need a multi-language admin panel though.

Could anyone recommend me any?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try globalize3 if you use rails 3 http://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3

Or globalize2 if you use rails 2 http://github.com/joshmh/globalize2